# How to change source cell content from output cells of filtered functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to edit/change the source cell content from the result of the outputs of the filtered functions. For example, I have a master sheet that have say 1000 rows and 50 columns, I am using vlookup and query etc to filter out the cells I want to see, and I want to be able to make change the cell without actually going back to the source cell. formulas will recirculate so it won't work, but I know that app script can make it work and I need help.

I have created a basic table (filters data > 25)

ID Data Filter Data to change

```
ID  Data    Filter  Data to change
a   12       55           b
b   55       30 
c   15       35 
d   25      
e   30      
f   22      
g   15      
h   9       
i   12      
j   20      
k   15      
l   35
```

I can get the script to look up "55" and get "b" but I can't get to the next step to get the co-ordinate of "b" and edit the "b" cell.

```
function changeToSourceCell() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var last = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();


  var searchCell=ss.getRange("C2").getValue();
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==searchCell){break};
  }

  ss.getRange("D2").setValue(data[nn][0]);

  }
```

I was hoping to find a way to find the coordinate to "b" cell and replace the "D2" in `ss.getRange("D2").setValue(data[nn][0]);`

Maybe I am doing it wrong or is there a more direct way of achieving what I needed?

Many Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** To identify the coordinates of the cell with the value 'b' in column A

**Solution**: In

```
for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==searchCell){break};
  }
```

when a match is found, the value of `nn` indicates the row which contains the value 'b'.

The data array is zero-based, i.e. the value of A1 is in data[0][0].

So data[2][0] corresponds to A3.

To get the target range, try:

```
ss.getRange(nn + 1, 1).setValue("new value");
```

Comment: Thanks! as I am new with Javascript this now makes more sense.